# space transform induced function transform

Tags: linear-transformations, representation-theory, transformation

I am reading the book by Ernest Vinberg, 'linear representations of groups'. On page 78, he considers the representation of SU(2). The function space $V_n$ he takes is the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree n in the variables $u_1$ and $u_2$. Then he defines a representation $\Phi$ of the group $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ in $V_n$ by the rule

$$ (\Phi_n (A)f)(u) = f(u A), $$

where $u = (u_1,u_2)$, $A\in SL_2(\mathbb{C})$, and $f\in V_n $. In more detail, if $A=[a_{ij}]$, then

$$ (\Phi_n (A)f)(u_1, u_2)  = f(a_{11}u_1+ a_{21}u_2, a_{12}u_1+ a_{22}u_2) .$$

He then states that

"**This definition agrees with the general rule by which transformations act on functions if one regards $u_1$ and $u_2$ as coordinates on the space $U$ dual to the space of column vectors in which $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ acts naturally, and one accordingly regards $V_n$ as a space of functions on $U$.**"

I checked that this definition indeed aligns with the association law. But it still looks strange to me. Generally, if we have a linear transform $A$ on a vector space, the induced transform of a function $f$ is defined as

$$ (\Psi(A)f )(r) = f(A^{-1} r) .$$

This definition is very intuitive. $A$ moves the point $A^{-1}r$ to $r$, and in doing so it carries the value of $f$ at $A^{-1}r$ to the point $r$.

In contrast, Vinberg's definition is not so intuitive. But why does it work? What is the relation between his definition and the more intuitive definition?

Comment: If $u$ is a row vector, then $uA=A^Tu^T$. Then $f(A^Tr)$ and $f(A^{-1}r)$ are related by an inner automorphism of the group $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$, namely $\alpha(A)=(A^T)^{-1}$. (This is not an inner automorphism in any other dimension than the $2\times2$ case.) Indeed, $\alpha(A)=JAJ^{-1}$ where $J=[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}]$. Would that be enough of an answer?

Comment: @runway44  But apparently his argument works for arbitrary number of $u$'s.

Comment: What argument? ${}$

Comment: @runway44  Anyway, his definition works for an arbitrary number of $u$'s.

Comment: If by "works" you mean the right-multiplication definition gives a representation of $SL_k$ for arbitrary $k$, then yes. If by "works" you means gives an *equivalent* definition to the inverse matrix one, then no.